# Strategy parse response from server

Tags: php, android, json, api

I am using a library to make API call to the Instagram API. And I am getting a response like this:

```
POST:  https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/timeline/
DATA: is_prefetch=0&feed_view_info=&seen_posts=&phone_id=4c14088a-94b7-49c3-bec3-12caad443c50&reason=pull_to_refresh&battery_level=100
← 200      15.19kB
RESPONSE: {"response": "Random Json Response"}
```

I want the value of the response key from here.
What is the strategy to parse it? Or this is a special kind of software architecture style like SOAP or REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is the [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function.

You would use it like so:

```
$response = apache_request_headers();
print_r($response);
```

This will generate an array where you will be able to retrieve the information that you need.

The `RESPONSE:` data is in the JSON format. So you will need to convert it to an array like so:

```
$responseData = json_decode($responseData, true);
print_r($responseData);
```